# How to use custom function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, large-data

I am new to data.table and hopefully someone can help me with this question. I will be much appreciated

Basically I have a custom function which take a date and return the quarter (I can't use the quarter function already available because this is user-defined quarter) Here is the quarter function:

```
mapQuarters <- function(date){
if(as.Date("2013-12-29") <= date & date <= as.Date("2014-03-29")) {
return(1)
} else if(as.Date("2014-03-30") <= date & date <= as.Date("2014-06-28")){
return(2)
} else if(as.Date("2014-06-29") <= date & date <= as.Date("2014-09-27")){
return(3)
} else if(as.Date("2014-09-28") <= date & date <= as.Date("2014-12-27")){
return(4)
} else return(0)
}
```

My DT has 3 mil rows and would like to add a column qrt based on the email_sent_dt in the data.

example of DT:

data[1:4]

```
    rn user_id receipts_id email_sent_dt from_domain order_item_subtotal
1:  1     230     8315895    2014-12-25  AMAZON.COM              100.00
2:  2     230     8315895    2014-12-25  AMAZON.COM              100.00
3:  3     230     6639980    2014-01-26  AMAZON.COM                9.99
4:  4     230     6639981    2014-01-26  AMAZON.COM               11.99
```

the code i use for assigning quarters:

```
data[,("qrt"):=mapQuarters(email_sent_dt),by=1:nrow(data)]
```

It is taking 36 secs to run 20k rows, so it won't be time efficient to run 3 mil rows. I am wondering if anyone can come up with a more efficient solution to this? I thought data.table is supposed to be very good with large data, so I must have done something wrong

Comment: Look also at `?findInterval`, which seems to be pertinent: `findInterval(email_sent_dt,as.Date(c("2013-12-29","2014-03-29","2014-06-28","2014-09-27","2014-12-27")))`.

Comment: I think the user can't use the quarter function because they are using custom quarters. If your data$email_sent_dt is already in date format how long does data$qrt = mapQuarters(data$email_sent_dt) take?

Comment: Are you using the packaged called `DT`? If not, you can remove the corresponding tag from your post.

Comment: Your custom function is not "vectorized", that means you iterate over each row of the data table (indicated by "by=1:nrow(data)") which is quite slow. You should use the vectorized "ifelse" statement instead in your custom function if you need to apply a custom function (and not one of the recommended standard functions)

Comment: what @RYoda said; another alternative if you were forced to use an atomic function is to do it `by=email_sent_dt` instead of by each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `findInterval` function is flexible and you can enter the extrema of each interval:

```
#just to make the example reproducible
require(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, newCol:= 
       findInterval(email_sent_dt,
       as.Date(c("2013-12-29", "2014-03-29", "2014-06-28", "2014-09-27", "2014-12-27")))]
```

**Data**

```
data<-structure(list(rn = 1:4, user_id = c(230L, 230L, 230L, 230L), 
receipts_id = c(8315895L, 8315895L, 6639980L, 6639981L), 
email_sent_dt = structure(c(16429, 16429, 16096, 16096), class = "Date"), 
from_domain = c("AMAZON.COM", "AMAZON.COM", "AMAZON.COM", 
"AMAZON.COM"), order_item_subtotal = c(100, 100, 9.99, 11.99
)), .Names = c("rn", "user_id", "receipts_id", "email_sent_dt", 
"from_domain", "order_item_subtotal"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class =    "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.